# Vertical alignment of bootstrap modal on mobiles

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This question seems to have been asked a number of times on github but I haven't come across any solutions:
https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1399

how can the modal be vertically aligned properly on small screens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: As of Bootstrap 2.0.2, this is no longer an issue. Basically, bootstrap now implements the solution proposed below, which I'll leave here for reference purposes.**

Generally, on small screens modals will fill out most of your window, so positioning relative to the button that triggered the modal doesn't make terribly much sense. What I usually do is just overwriting the modal position for phones:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .modal {
      top: 20px;
      // negative left margin to position horizontally.
      margin: 0 0 0 -280px; 
      // already in modals.less, just copied for clarification:
      left: 50%;  
      position: fixed;
   }
}
```

(This is in LESS, pure CSS solutions looks similar).

Comment: Isn't there a common *official* way to do this ?

Comment: Back in bootstrap 1.x, this was unfortunately the only way to go. In newer versions, this is solved by bootstrap.